# PHP fast Reporting in multiple formats

Tags: php, performance, pdf, gwt, symfony1

I'm building a gigantic app using SMARTGWT + JSON + Symfony PHP Framework + ORACLE

It's working pretty well so far, it's very fast due to the way gwt only gets what it need form the server and the low size of json responses.

But I need to generate reports as well, in pdf, excel, word, etc.

I've developed code in php that makes this happen, using tcpdf for example, but it's very slow when my queries fetch more than 1000 rows at a time.

I was wondering if you know of a way to make php faster, or to rely on another laguage using swig for example for generating the pdfs or the xlss from other files that I've already generated from php, all of this or course in less than 30 seconds so my end user isn't annoyed.

I know of mem cache and md5ing the queries so that you cache the html for later reuse if the data hasn't changed, but these solutions aren't fast enough, specially for pdf generation. It's too bad that php is so slow, and the fact that it doesn't allow native multithreading is not that good also.

Should I build C++ classes that build my reports faster and invoke these libraries as php extensions? Is there a way to use another scripting language that apache understands?

Any ideas will be truly appreciated as I will publish my project as an opensource framework for high demand web apps and enterprise web development.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [NginX](http://nginx.org/en/) and [PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/).